# C# Player move in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine, unityscript

The code is working very well to move a rigidbody with Right and Left arrows , but i can't understand what is the point of using maxVelocity and absVelX , i don't know their job in the code .. when i remove both it works very well , but it seems i will need both in the advanced game level . this is a course form lynda called " Unity 2d essential training by jesse freeman "

```
using UnityEngine;

using System.Collections;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour {

public float speed=10f;
public Vector2 maxVelocity=new Vector2(3,5);
public bool standing;
public float jetSpeed=15f;

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
            //Force resetted each frame
            var forceX = 0f;
            var forceY = 0f;
            var absVelX = Mathf.Abs (rigidbody2D.velocity.x);
            var absVelY = Mathf.Abs (rigidbody2D.velocity.y);

            if (Input.GetKey ("right")) {
                    if (absVelX < maxVelocity.x)
                            forceX = speed;

            transform.localScale=new Vector3(1,1,1);//Sprite orignal pose

            } else if (Input.GetKey ("left")) {
                    if (absVelX < maxVelocity.x)
                            forceX = -speed;

            transform.localScale=new Vector3(-1,1,1);//Sprite reversal pose

            }
    rigidbody2D.AddForce(new Vector2(forceX,forceY));
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the code provided it looks like that those variable are define limits of velocity, that assigned to the `rigidbody2D.velocity.x` (the call to `abs` is to compare absolute vectors magnitudes and not just coordinates).

It's not clear were the `rigidbody2D.velocity.x` is set, but the code presumes that somehow it may be bigger then `3` and program breaks on that maximum.

Comment: so is the code assigning rigidbody2D.velocity.x into absvelX after each frame ? so it's scalar now is set to "0" before any velocity applies ?

Comment: `Abs` means removing the sign. So if your `rigidbody2D.velocity.x` was equal -0.34, it becomes 0.34.

Comment: i know , what i meant is , is absvelX always == 0 ? , as before moving a player there is no velocity value !

Comment: if `velocity.x` value is 0, abs will too, yes.